# SQL COUNT the number purchase between his first purchase and the follow 10 months

Tags: sql

every customer has different first-time purchase date, I want to COUNT the number of purchases they have between the following 10 months after the first purchase?

sample table

```
TransactionID   Client_name PurchaseDate    Revenue
11               John Lee   10/13/2014      327
12               John Lee   9/15/2015       873
13               John Lee   11/29/2015      1,938
14               Rebort Jo  8/18/2013       722
15               Rebort Jo  5/21/2014       525
16               Rebort Jo  2/4/2015        455
17               Rebort Jo  3/20/2016       599
18               Tina Pe    10/8/2014       213
19               Tina Pe    6/10/2016       3,494
20               Tina Pe    8/9/2016        411
```

my code below just use ROW_NUM function to identify the first purchase, but I don't know how to do the calculations or there's a better way to do it?

```
SELECT client_name, 
       purchasedate, 
       Dateadd(month, 10, purchasedate) TenMonth, 
       Row_number() 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY client_name 
           ORDER BY client_name)        RM 
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, your `ORDER BY` should order the `PurchaseDate` `ASC` if you really wanted to ensure the earliest `PurchaseDate` is Row 1. You're getting lucky since your example data is already ordered ASC by the persons name. However, the answer below uses `MIN()` and works otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this - I assume you're using SQL Server from the presence of `DATEADD()` and the fact that you're using a window function (`ROW_NUMBER()`):

```
WITH myCTE AS (
    SELECT TransactionID, Client_name, PurchaseDate, Revenue
         , MIN(PurchaseDate) OVER ( PARTITION BY Client_name ) AS min_PurchaseDate
      FROM myTable
)
SELECT Client_name, COUNT(*)
  FROM myCTE
 WHERE PurchaseDate <= DATEADD(month, 10, min_PurchaseDate)
 GROUP BY Client_name
```

Here I'm creating a common table expression (CTE) with all the data, including the date of first purchase, then I grab a count of all the purchases within a 10-month timeframe.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer checks out valid: [Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/GAEVN71383). Per your example data `Rebort Jo` is the only one to have more than one purchase within the 10 months after the initial purchase. Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl ... Subquery to get the min purchase date, then LEFT JOIN to the main table to have a WHERE clause for the ten month date range, then count.

```html
SELECT Client_name, COUNT(mt.PurchaseDate) as PurchaseCountFirstTenMonths
FROM myTable mt
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT Client_name, MIN(PurchaseDate) as MinPurchaseDate GROUP BY Client_name) mtmin 
         ON mt.Client_name = mtmin.Client_name AND mt.PurchaseDate = mtmin.MinPurchaseDate 
WHERE mt.PurchaseDate >= mtmin.MinPurchaseDate  AND mt.PurchaseDate <= DATEADD(month, 10, mtmin.MinPurchaseDate)
GROUP BY Client_name
ORDER BY Client_name
```

btw I'm guessing there's some kind of ClientID involved, as nine character full name runs the risk of duplicates.

Comment: Define 'doesn't work'.  Perhaps I can make some changes to make it work.